# Slicing an Atomic Vector from a table and sorting it in Descending Order in R

Tags: r, dataframe, format, linear-regression, lm

Once created a linear regression model using R’s `lm()` function I want to write a piece of code where it sorts the `Estimate` vector from the `coefficients` and lists the greatest 5 estimate values are sorting the vector in descending order. How would I be able to do such a thing?

```
# Assume that im using the `price` field to compare the other fields in the `data` data frame
model <- lm(price~., data=data)
values= summary(model)$coefficients
```

The current output for the `values` variable from the coed above looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Should the intercept be included in the list?

Comment: In base R: `sort(summary(model)$coefficients[, 1], decreasing = TRUE)`

Comment: it would be great if you could indicate if the provided answer was helpful, and if so, consider accepting it so that others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
values %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  arrange(-Estimate)
```

if you just want a vector of the estimates you could add another line to the pipe with `pull(Estimate)`.